# Can I use $expand to get Managed Metadata column values?

Tags: 2013, rest, taxonomy

I want to get a list, using **REST**, which include Managed Metadata columns. Currently I get a `TermGuid` for these columns, which I then have to do more work on to get their actual default values.

Is there a way to do this all in one call? Something like:

```
/sites/mysite/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('My List')/items?$expand=managed_metadata
```

Answer (score 8):

`SP.Taxonomy.TaxonomyFieldValue` type exposes the following properties via SharePoint REST API:

- `Label`
- `TermGuid`
- `WssId`

### How to retrieve Taxonomy field values using SharePoint REST in JavaScript

Assume `Pages` library contains:

- `Category` single valued taxonomy field
- `Categories` mutli-valued taxonomy field

Then the following example demonstrates how to perform GET request to retrieve taxonomy field values:

```
function getJson(url,success,failure)
{
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET", 
      headers: { 
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose"
      }, 
      url: url, 
      success: success,
      failure: failure 
   });
}

function getListItems(listTitle,success,failure)
{
    var endpointUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('" + listTitle + "')/items";
    getJson(endpointUrl,
      function(data){
        success(data.d.results);    
      },
      failure);
}


//Usage
getListItems('Pages',
  function(items){
      //print info
      for(var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
          console.log(items[i].Category.Label);  //single-valued taxonomy field  
          if(items[i].Categories.results.length > 0) 
             console.log(items[i].Categories.results[0].Label);  //print first value of multiple taxonomy field
      }
  },
  function(error){
     console.log(JSON.stringify(error)); 
  }
);
```

But unfortunately there is a *known bug* with retrieving a Label from single-valued taxonomy field using SharePoint REST GET request.

The workaround is to perform POST request to retrieve taxonomy field values as demonstrated below:

```
function postJson(endpointUrl,payload,success,failure)
{
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST", 
      headers: { 
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
      }, 
      data: JSON.stringify(payload),
      url: endpointUrl, 
      success: success,
      failure: failure 
   });
}


function getListItems(listTitle, queryViewXml,success,failure)
{
   var queryPayload = { 
       'query':{ 
           '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.CamlQuery' },
           'ViewXml': queryViewXml
        } 
   }; 
   var endpointUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listTitle + "')/getitems";
   postJson(endpointUrl,queryPayload,
     function(data){
        success(data.d.results);    
     },failure);
}

//Usage
getListItems('Pages','<View><Query/></View>',
  function(items){
      //print info  
      for(var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
          console.log(items[i].Category.Label);  //single-valued taxonomy field  
          if(items[i].Categories.results.length > 0)  
             console.log(items[i].Categories.results[0].Label);  //print first value of multiple taxonomy field
      }
  },
  function(error){
     console.log(JSON.stringify(error)); 
  });
```

Comment: What's the known bug?

Comment: You could some details, for example here:http://sharepointificate.blogspot.co.uk/2014/05/taxonomy-columns-sharepoint-2013-list.html

Comment: Ah nice, I'm seeing just the number 1 for my labels as well.

Comment: MS still hasn't fixed this! So I'm guessing that I would need to translate all my select, filter, orderby, etc into CAML syntax? Or is there a way to combine the two?

Answer (score 7):

You can do a workaround using the TaxCatchAll field as long as you know which terms belong to which taxonomy field - if you have multiple.

```
/_api/web/Lists/GetByTitle('<list>')/Items/?$select=*,TaxCatchAll/Term&$filter=TaxCatchAll/Term eq 'Puzzlepart'&$expand=TaxCatchAll
```

Comment: I got this error
`The expression "*,TaxCatchAll/Term$filter=TaxCatchAll/Term eq 'termname'" is not valid.`

Comment: I missed a &. Edited my answer now to form a correct url.

Comment: That might work only for lists at the site collection level? I tried it on a subsite and I got the following error "The field 'TaxCatchAll' is not supported in query. The lookup list is in another web." Is there a way to do that on subsites?

Comment: I have no idea and never tried. We tend to use single site collections and a minimal of subsites these days. But might be that you have hit a boundary for this workaround.

Comment: I just added TaxCatchAll/ID, which allows me to map the values in TaxCatchAll to their corresponding columns.

For example:
`<d:MyLocation m:type="SP.Taxonomy.TaxonomyFieldValue">
<d:Label>5</d:Label>
<d:TermGuid>c8cb412b-ed99-4034-8ca7-5019940ec354</d:TermGuid>
<d:WssId m:type="Edm.Int32">5</d:WssId>
</d:MyLocation>`

and 

`<m:properties>
<d:ID m:type="Edm.Int32">5</d:ID>
<d:Term>Lab 2B</d:Term>
</m:properties>`

The 5 values connects the two. I'm working with multiple MMS columns.

Comment: Do you know by any chance whether pnpJs has implemented this fix??

Comment: Take a look at https://www.eliostruyf.com/using-sharepoint-renderlistdataasstream-api-fetch-lookup-single-managed-metadata-field-values/ using the RenderListDataAsStream API, which is also supported by pnpjs https://github.com/pnp/pnpjs/issues/318