# Get taxonomy and people column - REST API

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, rest

I have simple SharePoint custom list. It has 3 columns,

1) Title

2) Manager (Person or group type)

3) Type (Managed metadata - single value).

Now i tried to get the value of the list items. However, i am not able to get the values in a single REST API call.

If I use the standard `_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Test')/items(1)` and use `$expand`, i get the person name but taxonomy guid.

```
https://sitecollectionurl/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Test')/items(1)?expand=Manager&$select=Title,Manager/Title,Type
```

If I use the CAML query with REST API as below, then i get the taxonomy column label but i get the user's id value and not title.

```
var caml =  "<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='ID'/><Value Type='Number'>1</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>";

var requestData = { "query" :
           {
              "__metadata": 
              { "type": "SP.CamlQuery" }
              , "ViewXml": caml
           }
        };

$http({
            method: "POST",
            url: "https://sitecollectinonurl/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Test')/GetItems",
            data: requestData,
            headers: { "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose", "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose" , "X-RequestDigest": document.getElementById("__REQUESTDIGEST").value }
          });
```

Is there any way, I can get both the person column and taxonomy column in a single REST API call ?

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to do something like this:

```
url: _spPageContextInfo.siteServerRelativeUrl +
  "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('listName')/items?" +
  "$select=Author/ID,Author/Title,Author/EMail," +
  "TaxonomyColumn,"
  "TaxCatchAll/ID,TaxCatchAll/Term," +
  "&$expand=Author,TaxCatchAll"
```

You'll get objects back for Author, TaxonomyColumn, and TaxCatchAll. TaxonomyColumn will have the Term Set object information and TaxCatchAll will have the TaxonomyColumn term.

I am using these headers in my testing, but verbose ought to also work. (I don't want any metadata.)

```
          headers: {
              "Accept": "application/json; odata=nometadata"
          }
```

See [this post](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/119096/can-i-use-expand-to-get-managed-metadata-column-values) for more info.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. This works at site collection level but not at subsites unfortunately. I have make 2 rest calls :(

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. As long as you're going against a single list, it ought to work, whether the list in the the current site or some other site. Note that you are calling a different endpoint than I am: /GetItems vs. /items.

Comment: If i use the query at `https://sitecollectionurl`, it works. But the same query if i use at `https://sitecollectionurl/subsite` , it gives `The field 'TaxCatchAll' is not supported in query. The lookup list is in another web.` error. I am using the query you posted here - `getbytitle('listName')/items`

Comment: FYI - i have two similar lists with same columns(internal names and everything) . One is at the site collection and other is at the subsite. This query works correctly at the site collection but not at subsite.

Comment: Ah, ok. You're running into this problem: https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/329220-sharepoint-dev-platform/suggestions/9065329-enable-support-for-lookup-columns-in-other-webs-in The TaxCatchAll column is a hidden "lookup column" in the root site of the Site Collection.