# Get Value of Taxonomy Field single selection

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, taxonomyfieldvalue

My Code is below..

> function RetrieveProspect(ProspectID) {
>       var getItemsUrl = "/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('" + ListNameProspect + "')/items?$select=ID,Title,Domicile&$filter=(ID eq " + ProspectID + ")";

```
var promise = $.ajax({
    url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + getItemsUrl,
    type: "GET",
    headers: {
        "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",success: function (data) {
        ArrayRetrieved = data.d.results;
        if (ArrayRetrieved.length > 0) {
            console.log(ArrayRetrieved);
            //LICENSES
            for (var i = 0; i < ArrayRetrieved.length; i++) {$("#Domicile").append(ArrayRetrieved[i].Domicile.Label);   }
        }
    },
    error: function (error) {
        console.log("Error on Retrieve Service");
        console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
    }
});
```

}

the debug :[image]

The result : 487

I would like to display the value :(

Comment: check [this](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/119118/8068) answer here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The  solution i Found :

> ```
> var viewXml = {
>     ViewXml: "<View>" +
>         "<Query>" +
>         "<Where><Eq>" +
>         "<FieldRef Name='ID' />" +
>         "<Value Type='Number'>" + ProspectID + "</Value>" +
>         "</Eq></Where>" +
>         "</Query>" +
>         "</View>"
> }
> ```

```
var call = $.ajax({
    url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/Web/Lists/getByTitle('" + ListNameProspect + "')/GetItems(query=@v1)?" +
        "@v1=" + JSON.stringify(viewXml),
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    headers: {
        Accept: "application/json;odata=verbose",
        "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
    },

    success: function (data) {
        ArrayRetrieved = data.d.results;
        if (ArrayRetrieved.length > 0) {
            console.log(ArrayRetrieved);
            //LICENSES
            for (var i = 0; i < ArrayRetrieved.length; i++) { $("#Domicile").append(ArrayRetrieved[i].Domicile != null ? ArrayRetrieved[i].Domicile.Label : "");}
```

> error: function (error) {
>               console.log("Error on Retrieve Service");
>               console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
>           },
>       });